git revert after some further changes
Below is what I had in my tree:
commit 6ffbcdf6e3bdc8a6161c9f40838a1adafeb9e9ec (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: oneeyeman1 <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 29 00:42:34 2024 -0600

    Exclude binary release folders from trackng

commit f001e018977a901f80e45f2b9282b343dbf3b8b0
Author: oneeyeman1 <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 29 00:17:02 2024 -0600

    Fix compilation errors

commit 1cb781db7df04c6bff3db794cd19fdb7f92c3ff3
Merge: d8bf6c9a2c 3721cc53a1
Author: oneeyeman1 <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 28 22:54:58 2024 -0600

    Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler

commit d8bf6c9a2c3b8ec8f4e2f6cc773067eda9ffe97e
Author: oneeyeman1 <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 28 22:54:16 2024 -0600

    Add Release configuration to the project

commit 3721cc53a1cbefee5dfe9af0382c26a86b5d0ffb
Merge: f2dd44a218 ad8d29b501
Author: Igor Korot <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Nov 27 12:11:43 2024 -0600

    Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler

commit f2dd44a218e775fb71d82d913ad9389e6e75cbb4
Author: Igor Korot <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Nov 27 12:11:36 2024 -0600

    Handle OK button press

What I realized is that with d8bf6c9a2c3b8ec8f4e2f6cc773067eda9ffe97e I accidentally broke the Debug build of my program, trying to make it.
So I need to revert it.
Unfortunately there is another commit - f001e018977a901f80e45f2b9282b343dbf3b8b0 which depends on the one after the breakage.
So what I did was -
git checkout master
and about to run git revert d8bf6c9a2c3b8ec8f4e2f6cc773067eda9ffe97e.
But I'm curious - will everything else be preserved correctly? Will I still have my commits after the improper one?

The documentation at git-revert(1) explains how git revert works. Note: if you were already on master like the log implies, git checkout master does nothing.

@Ry-,, so I presume it will be handled correctly and I should just run it...

Yep, that’s right.

I'm guessing there is a misunderstanding about what git revert actually does. Suppose you start with your branch's current state, and then you manually undo all of the changes that were made in the bad commit, and then stage and commit that. This is exactly what revert will do, but automatically. The fact that later commits modified the bad commit doesn't really matter, except that it might increase the chances of having conflicts, which if you have any you will have to resolve. You'd have to resolve them whether you use revert or do it manually.

Note there's a different command, git reset, which can move the branch pointer to a different commit. It's possible you were thinking of reset instead of revert when you asked this question, since it seems like part of your question is asking if any commits will be removed from the branch if you "revert" a specific commit. Since revert only adds a new commit, it won't remove any others. But if you reset to the bad commit, then you would remove commits...
